# AOSP build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: android, android-source

I got this error when tried to build the AOSP build

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-8.0.0_r33 --depth=1
```

I can't find anyone who experienced the same.

```
[  5% 3232/63193] Lex: applypatch <= bootable/recovery/edify/lexer.ll
FAILED: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libedify_intermediates/lexer.cpp 
/bin/bash -c "prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex/flex-2.5.39 -oout/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libedify_intermediates/lexer.cpp bootable/recovery/edify/lexer.ll"
flex-2.5.39: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[  5% 3239/63193] target StaticLib: li...IES/libv8src_intermediates/libv8src.a)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
14:04:56 ninja failed with: exit status 1
build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
```

Which bring me to the point the issue may lay down in the environment.

VirtualBox, 8gb RAM, 160gb space, Ubuntu 18.04

Does anyone have a proposal what might go wrong here?

Comment: Install 32-bit version of `Flex` and retry.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, it doesn't help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try running `export LC_ALL=C` before building.

I had a similar error when building on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I use above command, howerer, I still got the error